# How Fix TCP IPs check is online or offline with Port

Tags: tcp

Problem is when I it's chack IPs is online or Offline, it's give me offline ips, like if I get 3k online ips 1k ips offline show in RDP, i just want it's chack RDP Online ips.

private async Task IsAddressOnlineAsync(IPAddress ipAddress, int portNumber)

```
    {

        try

        {

            using (var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))

            {

                var connectTask = socket.ConnectAsync(ipAddress, portNumber);

                var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(5000); // Set a timeout for the connection attempt

                // Wait for either the connection to succeed or the timeout to elapse

                await Task.WhenAny(connectTask, timeoutTask);

                if (connectTask.IsCompleted && socket.Connected)

                    return true;

            }

        }

        catch

        {

            return false;

        }

        return false;

    }
```

private async Task IsAddressOnlineAsync(IPAddress ipAddress, int portNumber)

```
    {

        try

        {

            using (var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))

            {

                var connectTask = socket.ConnectAsync(ipAddress, portNumber);

                var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(5000); // Set a timeout for the connection attempt

                // Wait for either the connection to succeed or the timeout to elapse

                await Task.WhenAny(connectTask, timeoutTask);

                if (connectTask.IsCompleted && socket.Connected)

                    return true;

            }

        }

        catch

        {

            return false;

        }

        return false;

    }
```